# Use color coding from pandas style object to another pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-styles

I want to use the color coding from a pandas style object and apply the exact same coloring to the corresponding cells in another dataframe with the same size. The data is different in the two dataframes which means i can not use the same styling function.

I have tried using style.render() from the style object with the desired color and then apply it to the new dataframe. This did not work for me though.

EDIT:
I have posted a picture below of what i have tried to do. In the picture i use the .render() method to get the HTML of the dataframe with the color coding and apply it to a new dataframe, but without success.

[styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHIBz.png)

Comment: Please show us what you tried, paste your code and where you are facing problem?

Comment: I have added a picture with an example of what i am trying to accomplish

Comment: did you try with , `style1=df1.style.apply(highlight_max)` , `style2 = df2.style` , `style2.use(style1.export())` then `style2`?

Comment: Yes, i have tried this. The problem with this is that it simply uses the same styling function (highlight_max) on df2. I want to use the same coloring schema that that is generated when using the styling function on df1 and then apply this coloring to df2